# Is it possible to store a list of ids as an attribute for an object in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement a voting system where users can upvote/downvote links posted by other users. A user can only vote on a link once, so before I execute upvote or downvote I need to check if the user has already voted and if they had already voted, wheather they upvoted or downvoted, so that I can disable the button for the other.

There are a few ways to do this. The most immediate solution that comes to me is to have two additional columns in the link model, one to store a list of ids of users that upvoted and the other to store a list of ids of users that downvoted.

Two concerns arise in my mind. One, is this even considered a good practice (in terms of database efficiency) and if it is the best way to do it, how do I store a list of ids as an attribute for the model? What would be the data type I need to enter for the migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not a good practice storing votes as list of ids in a field. You are violating the 1NF of your database. [1NF wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Imagine this happening on a scale of millions of votes, not only is the storage inefficient, but also imagining fetching and scanning the whole list if you want to see if a voter voted for given object.

The better solution for this will be to have A `"Vote"` table with columns like `"voter_id", "voted_for_id", "vote_value"`.

Proper indexes will ensure that you will be able to do most of your operations very efficiently even on very large data. e.g.:- finding number of upvotes/downvotes for a candidate or finding whether a person has already voted for a candidate etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to store a list of ids as an attribute for an object in rails?

Yes, it possible. One way is using `Array` datatype as

```
def change
  add_column :links, :upvote_user_ids, :array, :default => []
end
```

> is this even considered a good practice (in terms of database efficiency)

No, it is not at all recommended. Over the period of time the list will explode degrading your system thoroughly..

Consider [`acts_as_votable`](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gem, this solves your query elegantly..